# iTerm2 - text not wrapping with emoji in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I am making a personal theme for oh-my-zsh! but with my current prompt the text doesn't wrap onto a new line and instead does this: [image: terminal]

`PROMPT='☕️ %B%F{#74A12E}%~$FG[040]%F{#6f4e37}$(git_prompt_info)%b $reset_color➜ '`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want it to look like instead?

Comment: `zsh` can accurately compute the effect of `%F{...}` on the length of the prompt, but not arbitrary escape sequences that I assume `$FG[040]` and `$reset_color` produce.